# Значению интервала не может быть присвоено отрицательное число.C#

Tags: c#, график

Данный код строит график функции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и график произвольной функции, код выдаёт ошибку с отрицательными числами в значении `Stepdx`  (System.ArgumentException: "Значению интервала не может быть присвоено отрицательное число.) с положительными всё работает, помогите решить данную проблему и подскажите сам код вообще правильно строит график или я перепутал где Xmin и Xmax.
Код:

```
namespace _99999999
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            

            // Считываем с формы требуемые значения
            double Xmin0 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            double Xmaxk = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            double Stepdx = double.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            double b = double.Parse(textBox4.Text);
            double a = double.Parse(textBox5.Text);
            // Количество точек графика
            int count = (int)Math.Ceiling((Xmaxk - Xmin0) / Stepdx) + 1;

            // Массив значений X – общий для обоих графиков
            double[] x = new double[count];
            // Два массива Y – по одному для каждого графика
            double[] y1 = new double[count];
            double[] y2 = new double[count];
            
            // Расчитываем точки для графиков функции
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                // Вычисляем значение X
                x[i] = Xmin0 + Stepdx * i;

                // Вычисляем значение функций в точке X
                y1[i] = x[i] * Math.Sin(Math.Sqrt(x[i] + b - a)); ;
                y2[i] = (Math.Sqrt(x[i]));
            }
            // Настраиваем оси графика
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = Xmin0;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = Xmaxk;

            // Определяем шаг сетки
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = Stepdx; //Строка с ошибкой
            // Добавляем вычисленные значения в графики
            chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y1);
            chart1.Series[1].Points.DataBindXY(x, y2);
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: System.ArgumentException: "Значению интервала не может быть присвоено отрицательное число.

Comment: ну а что вы присвоить то пытаетесь значению интервала?

Comment: Я пишу в `textBox3` значение шага dx тобишь -0,2

Comment: вот вам и пишет `Значению интервала не может быть присвоено отрицательное число.`

Comment: Логично, а мне нужно именно это число, что сделать чтобы можно было присваивать отрицательные числа

Comment: @Александр у вас это не получится. Представляете, вас спрашивают, с каким шагом нарисовать сетку, а вы - `-0.2`! И как рисовать сетку с шагом -0.2? Это примерно так же сложно как съесть -1 яблоко. Что не так с сеткой будет, если вы выберете шаг 0.2? Ваш вопрос звучит примерно так: "я делю на ноль, у меня ошибка `на ноль делить нельзя`, но мне надо делить на ноль, как это сделать?". Никак.

Comment: ищите другой UI контрол значит, который бы позволил иметь отрицательный шаг. Хотя не понимаю проблемы, почему бы вместо того, чтобы от большей точки в меньшуу не отрисовать от меньшей в большую?

Comment: Задание требует использовать -0,2, к сожалению

Comment: Вы не сможете задать отрицательный шаг. Ищите другой способ.

Comment: Вообще задание звучит так: Таблицу данных получить путем изменения параметра X с шагом dx. Может я что то не понял? Вроде всё верно пытаюсь сделать

Comment: Не так поняли, вам значения для построения надо с этим шагом вычислить. А вы сетку для графика пытаетесь к этому условию притянуть. Задавайте шаг 0.2 и переворачивайте список значений задом-наперед для вывода.

Comment: А вот оно как, благодарю. Это значит от шага сетки (строки) можно вообще избавиться?

Comment: Ни что не мешает вам это проверить на практике. Кстати метод `Array.Reverse` вам может пригодиться.